# React setState callback coming before render

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to get an alert to pop up after a certain number of cards are drawn, but when attempting to use the callback in setState the alert pops before the render occurs.

```
checkWin() {
        if (cards[Object.keys(cards)[12]].number === 0) {
            alert("GAME OVER");
        }
    }

    drawCard() {
        let cardNumber;
        do {
            cardNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Object.keys(cards).length));
        }
        while (cards[Object.keys(cards)[cardNumber]].number === 0);
        var card = cards[Object.keys(cards)[cardNumber]];
        card.number = card.number - 1;
        console.log()
        this.setState({
            card: card.images[card.number + 1],
            total: this.state.total -1,
            description: card.description
        }, this.checkWin());
    }
```

I have tried putting the function in the callback and it doesn't work either.

edit: the alert comes up before the new card is shown

it works as intended by changing checkWin() to this:

```
        if (cards[Object.keys(cards)[12]].number === 0) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                alert("GAME OVER");
            }, 500);
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by before the render occurs ?

Comment: the alert comes up before the screen changes to show the new card which is being changed in setState

Comment: You are calling the function on runtime. Change it to this in the callback:
`}, () => this.checkWin());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing the callback function wrong. try this

```
        this.setState({
            card: card.images[card.number + 1],
            total: this.state.total -1,
            description: card.description
        }, () => this.checkWin() );   ///-> see here
```

Comment: Have already tried that, it still pops before it renders

Comment: the rendering takes some time. you can delay the popup by 100ms